# Why does my app crashes when I stop threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

When I press Start monitoring it runs perfectly, but as soon as I press stop, it crashes immediatly.

PD: If I add `self.thread.join()` at the end of `start_monitoring()` function, it'll crash as soon as I press Start.

This is my `MainWindow` Class:

```
class MainWindow_UI(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow_UI,self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('./widgets/mainwindow.ui',self)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.watch = OnMyWatch()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.watch.run)
        
        self.start_button.released.connect(self.start_monitoring)
        self.stop_button.released.connect(self.stop_monitoring)
        
        self.show()
                
    def start_monitoring(self):
        self.thread.start()
        
    def stop_monitoring(self):
        self.thread._stop()

class OnMyWatch():
    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()
    def run(self):
        watchDirectory = path_to_download_folder
        event_handler = Handler()
        logging_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler,watchDirectory,recursive=True)
        self.observer.schedule(logging_handler,watchDirectory, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        self.condition = True
        try:
            while self.condition == True:
                sleep(1)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
        self.observer.join()

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        
    def on_any_event(self,event):
        self.filter_files()
```

The Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Documents\PyTools\S-Watch\main.py", line 74, in stop_monitoring
    self.thread._stop()
  File "C:\Users\Fran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1047, in _stop
    assert not lock.locked()
AssertionError
```

Solution:
Turns out you can't reuse threads, and once you use `thread.start()` they're cached (I think) so I just did this:

```
class MainWindow_UI(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow_UI,self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('./widgets/mainwindow.ui',self)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.watch = OnMyWatch()
        -----------
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.watch.run)
        ^^^^^ DELETED
        
        self.logo = self.findChild(QLabel,'logo')
        self.start_button = self.findChild(QPushButton,'start_button')
        self.stop_button = self.findChild(QPushButton,'stop_button')
        self.config_button = self.findChild(QPushButton,'settings_button')
        self.close_button = self.findChild(QPushButton,'close_button')
        
        self.start_button.released.connect(self.start_monitoring)
        self.stop_button.released.connect(self.stop_monitoring)
        self.config_button.released.connect(self.open_config)
        self.close_button.released.connect(self.close)
        
        self.show()

    def start_monitoring(self):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.watch.run)
        ^^^^ADDED
        self.thread.start()
        self.start_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.stop_button.setEnabled(True)
        self.start_button.setStyleSheet('color: #6c6c6c;background-color: #141414;border: none')
        self.stop_button.setStyleSheet('color: #b9b9b9;background-color: #474747;border: none')
        self.logo.setPixmap(QPixmap('green_logo.png'))
        
    def stop_monitoring(self):
        self.watch.stop()
        --------
        self.thread = None
        ^^^^ADDED
        self.start_button.setEnabled(True)
        self.stop_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.start_button.setStyleSheet('color: #b9b9b9;background-color: #474747;border: none')
        self.stop_button.setStyleSheet('color: #6c6c6c;background-color: #141414;border: none')
        self.logo.setPixmap(QPixmap('logo.png'))
```

This way it'll create and remove the thread every time.

Comment: Crashes how?  If there's a traceback, you must give us the whole traceback.

Comment: Here's the [Traceback](https://imgur.com/jehefAB)

Comment: Also: 1. `thread.join()` blocks everything until the thread quits, so you should certainly **not** put it right after starting the thread; 2. AFAIK, `_stop()` is not only "private", but also doesn't *actually* stop the thread; 3. since there is absolutely ***nothing*** that stops the `while` loop (by setting `condition` to `False`), the thread will never stop, will make your program hang and eventually crash (depending on the OS). 4. Use [QFileSystemWatcher](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html).

Comment: Please [edit] your post and paste the traceback as text, not using images.

Comment: I've tried adding a stop function to OnMyWatch class to set condition to False, but it keeps crashing, so I'm not sure what I'm suppossed to do.

Comment: @musicamante I'm sorry, done.

Comment: @Sylph1de Then share the code about that attempt.

Comment: No, add that to the question!

Comment: Threads should always have a way to gracefully stop themselves.  It's never healthy to stop one from outside.  If you set `self.watch.condition = False`, the thread will stop, right?  Why aren't you doing that?

Comment: Ok, fixed guys. It turns out I was creating the thread during the `__init__` function and the problem with that it's that you can't reuse threads.
I eddited to add the solution. Thank you really much.

Comment: @Sylph1de Ok. Note that if you use QThreads, you *can* reuse it. This is because QThread is *not* "the" thread, but the interface to a thread. As long as the thread for the QThread object has finished (its `run()` has returned), you can start it again.